# How to call a top level kotlin function in java?

Tags: java, kotlin

Assume a kotlin function is defined outside of a class as top level function.

`Util.kt`:

```
class Util {
   fun bar()
}
fun foo(){}
```

How can I call method `foo()` in Java?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`foo` will be compiled to a static function in a class whose name is that of the Kotlin source file with the suffix `Kt` - so in this case, you can say `UtilKt.foo()`.

Comment: If the Kotlin code is yours, however, consider instead putting this at the top of your Kotlin file.

    @file:JvmName("Something")

Then in Java:

    Something.foo();

Comment: @AdamAugusta: Neat; I didn't know that you could do that - that certainly looks nicer.